# Ruby on Rails, can't get cancan to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cancan

I have been trying to get cancan to work all day. I have started over several times using different tutorials but I keep getting the same errors.

It's pretty simple, I have User account (created with Devise) which can have one role, either Admin or User. Here is the ability class:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new
    if user.role? :admin
      can :manage, :all
    end
  end
end
```

In the profile controller I have the line `load_and_authorize_resource`,  the class User contains `ROLES = %w[admin user]`. Going to `http://localhost:3000/profiles/` gives me the error

`wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)` in `app/models/ability.rb:6:in`initialize'`

Using the alternative method `user.admin?` gives

```
undefined method `admin?' for #<User:0x5b34c10>
```

Googling the error above gives many results so I'm not the only person having this problem, but none of the solutions have worked for me.

And yes I have added the role column to the User table

```
class AddRoleToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :role, :string
  end
end
```

added the Gem, ran bundle install and restarted the server.

Comment: so are you sure you have these `role?` and `admin?` methods?

Comment: The User table has a role column. I should be able to do user.role to get the role. I have read the Wiki on cancan and it should work without defining methods https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Role-Based-Authorization

Comment: so just check it like `if user.role == 'admin'` CanCan doesn't create any special methods for you

Comment: @nash From rails console
`if User.first.role == "admin" 
puts "user is admin"
 end`  --   returns "user is admin"

Comment: Yes but the fact that you have the necessary database columns doesn't mean that you automagically have methods called `admin?` or `role?`. You need to define them yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Providing you have the following this should work:

**Ability.rb**

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability
  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.new # guest user
   # raise user.role?(:administrator).inspect
    if user.role? :administrator

      can :manage, :all
      can :manage, User

    elsif user.role? :user
      can :read, :all

    end

  end
end
```

**RoleUser.rb**

```
class RoleUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  # attr_accessible :title, :body
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role

end
```

**Role**

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
```

**User.rb**

```
 class User < ActiveRecord::Base

 has_and_belongs_to_many :roles

  def role?(role)
    self.roles.find_by_name(role.to_s.camelize)
  end
```

You need this as you are defining your roles, finding them, converting the role to a string and camelizing it.

**seeds.rb**

```
%w(Employee Administrator).each { |role| Role.create!(:name => role)}
```

creates an array `User` and `Administrator`.

Should you follow these steps correctly you this should work. And also ensure you have the following migrations:

```
class UsersHaveAndBelongsToManyRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def self.up
    create_table :roles_users, :id => false do |t|
      t.references :role, :user
    end
  end

  def self.down
    drop_table :roles_users
  end
end
```

Then in your view you should use the `can?` by doing something like

```
<% if can? :manage, User %> 
  .......
    ....
  ...
<% end %>
```